# De-serialize Java class using alibaba fastjson

Tags: java, spring, fastjson

I'm trying to de-serialize class from JSON string using library com.alibaba.fastjson. This is the class:

```
@Getter
@ToString
@Setter
@JSONType(naming = PropertyNamingStrategy.CamelCase)
   public class SiteInfo {
   private String id;
...
   @JSONField(name = "keywords")
   private String keyWords;
...
}
```

After I run the code, the value of keyWords=null; In other hand, if I changing it to "private String keywords;" everything works fine. So I can't use the camelcase (according to java conventions). 
In need some thing similar like @JsonProperty("keywords") from Jackson library, but for the alibaba fast json.

Comment: do you use the latest version of fastjson? and can you show the json string or the whole code?

Comment: I'm using 1.2.62 version of fastjson.

Comment: I did the demo project, and you could find it here https://github.com/JaS4083/demoFastJson

to test it in Postman, ulr: http://localhost:8080/show (Post)
body -> raw, JSON :
`{
    "id": "99201",
 "name": "BidderTestMobileWEB",
 "domainname": "junk1.com",
 "cat": [
  "IAB1",
  "IAB2"
 ],
 "keywords": "investment",
 "page": "http://www.nexage.com",
 "search": "crypto currency",
 "privacypolicy": 33
}`

Comment: the returned String: `SiteInfo(id=99201, name=BidderTestMobileWEB, domainName=null, cat=[IAB1, IAB2], keyWords=null, page=http://www.nexage.com, search=crypto currency, privacyPolicy=0)` It doesn't map the value for **domainName=null, keyWords=null**, and  **privacyPolicy=0** because of  the camelCase

Comment: your spring boot project seems not configured json serial/deserialization with fastjson. spring boot uses jackson by default so `@JSONField` takes no effect. use jackson's `@JsonProperty`instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I excluded jackson from dependencies and also configured my application to use fastjson as a converter, based on this example https://gist.github.com/wxcsdb88/164973ea77fbb0434bb8e7fc3163a578#file-spring-boot-fastjson-config-java
now it works !